# How to create 3D buttons and make them clickable?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to apply a 3D effect for all my buttons.

I have written the following CSS code for my 3 buttons, could anyone give me an idea how to apply a 3D effect on the buttons?

```css
button{
    height:60px;
    width:60px;
    border:none;
    background:#00ffff;
    color:#ff3300;
}
```

```html
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
<button>3</button>
```

Comment: If my answer helped, please consider accepting it :)

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for the `box-shadow` effect?

```css
button{
  cursor:pointer;
  height:60px;
  width:60px;
  border:none;
  background:#00ffff;
  color:#ff3300;
  box-shadow:5px 5px 5px #888888;
}

button:active {
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #666666;
}
```

```html
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
<button>3</button>
```

Your could also go for something more complicated but better looking using the `:active` selector:

```css
button {
    cursor:pointer;
    color: black;
    background-color: #00ffff;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 9px 0px #00b3b3, 0px 9px 25px #00b3b3;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 9px 0px #00b3b3, 0px 9px 25px #00b3b3;
    box-shadow: 0px 9px 0px #00b3b3, 0px 9px 25px #00b3b3;
    margin: 40px;
    width: 140px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all .1s ease;
    border:none;
    display:block;
}

button:active {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px #00b3b3, 0px 3px 6px #00b3b3;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px #00b3b3, 0px 3px 6px #00b3b3;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px #00b3b3, 0px 3px 6px #00b3b3;
}
```

```html
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
<button>3</button>
```

Or for a 'push-down' 3D button effect, modify the above code a little bit:

```css
button {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    margin: 40px;
    width: 140px;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: none;
    background-color: #00ffff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 30px;
  
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.1s;
    transition: all 0.1s;
  
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 9px 0px #00b3b3;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 9px 0px #00b3b3;
    box-shadow: 0px 9px 0px #00b3b3;
}

button:active {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px #00b3b3;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px #00b3b3;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px #00b3b3;
    top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
<button>3</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Change box shadow and shadow color to beautify:**

```css
button{
 position:relative;
    height:60px;
    width:60px;
    border:none;
    background:#00ffff;
    color:#ff3300; 
 margin:5px;
 border-radius:7px 5px;
 outline: none;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 9px 1px #94a1a5;
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 9px 1px #94a1a5;
     box-shadow: 2px 9px 1px #94a1a5;
}
button:active{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px #ecd4d1;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px #ecd4d1;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px #ecd4d1;
    position:relative;
    top:7;
}
```

```html
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
<button>3</button>
```